# MacOS Switch between active windows of application in active display

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I have 2 displays and its really annoying that cycling between windows of an app jumps between displays.

I want to cycle between windows of an app on the active display only (of the currently active window).

Thanks

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? Cycling between open windows, assuming it works like Windows' ALT-TAB, is always about ALL of the visible programs on the system. You would need some 3rd party software to change a default system behavior, I would guess.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/193937/85275 specifically that if you use separate Spaces this should do what you need [at the cost of separate Spaces being a paradigm shift in itself]

Comment: @music2myear - because Mac, unlike Windows, considers all open windows of any given app as a single process, it's possible to differentiate between swapping apps [Cmd/Tab] & swapping windows [CMd /`] & although it doesn't differentiate per display, it does differentiate per Space (Desktop). There's also a sub function in Cmd/Tab to select a specific window too, but it's clunky, and even a function to swap between *all* open windows in a given Space [which is frankly unusable;)

Comment: @Tetsujin I used different spaces with the option Displays have separate spaces.
but still the CMd /` cycles between all the app window in all spaces.
Its not possible to develop an application to cycle between the app windows in the same space only?

Comment: I can't repro. If I move a window to another space it becomes excluded from the 'cycle' list.